# Getting Access Token from Azure AD without user credentials

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, adal

I am using ADAL in order to log in to my app which is being made in Xamarin.Forms against Azure AD. That is all working fine, however I now want to be able to register a new user and to do this need an access token to pass to the constructor of one of my methods.

However, as the user hasn't yet been registered, I need to be able to get an access token from Azure AD without actually supplying any user credentials. I have been told that in a normal web app, I'd be able to send the client id and app key so that Azure AD would know who I was and then send me back an access token but I can't figure out how to implement this in a cross-platform Xamarin app.

If anyone has come across this before, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use of an app key in a native application is not recommended, regardless sof the dev stack you use to implement it. The reason is that generally devices should not be trusted with secrets. Furthermore, secret distribution is complicated (you can't embed it in the app code).
As a result, ADAL for Xamarin (and all the other flavors of ADAL meant to be used in native apps) does not expose any method for acquiring tokens with an app key.
From a antive app you really need to bootstrap secure communication with a user identity. Once you have that, you can do all sorts of interesting things on the server side (e.g. you API can, given that is running on the server, obtain tokens as an app).
HTH
V.

Comment: So if I secure a connection using the user identity, does that mean that I can acquire an access token from Azure AD without having to input or send any user credentials?

Comment: From the native app to your web API, you *need* to authenticate as a user in order to get a token. Once your API is executing, it can obtain new tokens on the server side without user intervention - but you can't secure the call to your API without an initial token, and to stress the point on a native client that token must be obtained from a user. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn499820.aspx for a list of token acquisition patterns Azure AD supports

Comment: Ok, so if I can't acquire a token without authenticating as a user, how do I register new users in Azure AD? If I am registering a new user, they won't yet have the credentials needed to authenticate with the API, or do I not need to pass a token when registering a new user for my app?

Comment: You do it from a web application, which can have its own credentials and obtain a token without a user. That is not an option for an ap running on a device.